# Django Inlines and DateTimeField

Tags: django, events, backend, inline-formset

I'm trying to create simple Event app, so I've decided to create event and some inline event occurances:

```
class EventOccurenceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.EventOccurance
    form = forms.EventOccuranceForm
    pass


class EventAdmin(TranslatableAdmin):
    list_display = [ "internal_name"]
    inlines = [
        EventOccurenceInline,
    ]
    pass
```

and here is forms.py:

```
class EventOccurenceForm(TranslatableModelForm):
    start_date = forms.DateTimeField()
    end_date = forms.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        model = models.EventOccurence
```

But, when I open my backend I see only simple inputs instead of DateTime pickers, and even labels for those fields say nothing:

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone know how to use those widgets inside inlines? What am I doing wrong?

thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: does it work if you dont specify form in the inline?

Comment: @Rohan, no, now it shows nothing at all.

Comment: I've heard of people having issues with adblockers and DateTime widgets

Comment: @PT114, no adblocker installed :(

Comment: Where does `TranslatableAdmin` and `TranslatableModelForm` come from?

Comment: @Nick, that's django-hvad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you're declaring the `start_date` and `end_date` fields in the `EventOccurenceForm` class without any arguments.

Here is a quote from Django's "Creating forms from models" documentation in the [Overriding the default field types or widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets) section:

> If you explicitly instantiate a form field like this, Django assumes
>   that you want to completely define its behavior; therefore, default
>   attributes (such as `max_length` or `required`) are not drawn from the
>   corresponding model. If you want to maintain the behavior specified in
>   the model, you must set the relevant arguments explicitly when
>   declaring the form field.

Why are you declaring the `start_date` and `end_date` fields in the `EventOccurenceForm` class, anyway? Is it because you're trying to only have those two fields in the form? If that's the case, you should use the `fields` attribute of the inner `Meta` class instead.

I'm assuming the `EventOccurence` model's `start_date` and `end_date` fields are `DateField`s and, thus, within Django admin, they will have the `AdminDateWidget` widget by default. If, for some reason, that isn't the case and you can't change the model, you could always use the `widgets` attribute of the `EventOccurenceForm` class's inner `Meta` class, like this:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget

class EventOccurenceForm(TranslatableModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.EventOccurence
        widgets = {
            'start_date': AdminDateWidget,
            'end_date': AdminDateWidget,
        }
```

Comment: Adam, thanks a lot for your help. It appeared to be a bit different kind of bug, but your answer has shown the right direction. The problem was in my Model declaration. It had "__auto_add_now__" parameter which blocked entire field from being displayed inside the form. As soon as I removed that parameter and used your widget declaration everything started to work like a charm.